# Запретить выполнение <script>

Tags: javascript

Как запретить выполнение определенных скриптов при переходе в мобильную версию сайта? Дизайн разделен только в стилях css. Требуется отключить ненужные скрипты для устройств с шириной экрана менее 1024.

Comment: никак, только прописывая условия выполнения в самих скриптах

Comment: а может у меня разрешение на мониторе стоит `800х600`, у меня теперь не должны выполняться скрипты? Просто условие, как подметил @Grundy, в скрипты ставь, типа `if (isMobile()) return false; <continue script code>`. В интернете можно найти множество способов, в распознании клиентского приложения с которого он сидит